# Doctrine only select last entry of collection

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I have the following Entity :

```php
class Product
{
     /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\StockEntry", mappedBy="product")
     *
     * @Groups({"product:read", "product:read:all"})
     */
    private Collection $stockEntries;

    public function getStockEntries(): Collection
    {
        return $this->stockEntries;
    }

    public function getLastBuyPrice(): float
    {
        /** @var StockEntry $lastEntry */
        $lastEntry =  $this->getStockEntries()->last();
        if ($lastEntry) {
            return $lastEntry->getBuyPrice() ?: 0.;
        }
        return 0.;
    }
}
```

My problem is that when I call my `getLastBuyPrice()` method, All `StockEntries` are retrieved, which can be very long (a product can have hundreds of stock entries). I'm looking for a way to rewrite `getLastBuyPrice()` so that only the most recent `StockEntry` is retrieved to compute the lastBuyPrice.

Comment: You are using logic inside your entity wich is a bad pratictice to retreive the last element i sugget to use a query to acheive that. Using a query will make the fetch much faster instead of retreiving the full collection and get the last element.

Comment: Short of using DQL or custom query. If you absolutely need the latest entry from the Product entity, use after delete update and insert triggers or event dispatcher (if relying only on the ORM) on the StockEntry table to maintain the latest entry state by referenced id in a separate table or the product table. Then you can add a `$latestStockEntry` association to your Product entity for the new reference as a `OneToOne` relationship.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend that you create a method in "StockEntryRepository".
This method will retrieve the last item you need without iterating through all of the items.